# Back key issue while sliding menu is open in android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

I came across issues which are being occured due to improper handling of <kbd>Back</kbd> key operation.

**Issues:**

1. Keyboard is present on the screen along with sliding drawer (i.e. navigation drawer in terms of Android programming).
2. If sliding menu is open and if user press back key then it should close sliding menu, not going to back to previous screen.

After following below steps you can see, sliding menu is still present on the screen and screen redirects to previous screen, instead pressing <kbd>Back</kbd> key should close sliding menu if its open otherwise redirects to previous screen if any.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Launch app
2. Open sliding menu (i.e. Navigation drawer) and select any site.
3. click on *Search Questions* input box and it will show Keyboard.
4. Now open sliding menu again, keep as it is open and press <kbd>Back</kbd> key.
5. Press <kbd>Back</kbd>, it will hide keyboard.
6. Again press <kbd>Back</kbd>, it will redirect to Feed screen in background and Sliding menu is open as it is.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for reporting this! It'll be fixed in the next update.

Comment: I just got update and I have noticed 2nd issue is resolved but 1st is as its in current app.

Comment: As far as I know, Status-completed tag only used if bug/issue is already fixed but here 1st issue is still not resolved after 2-3 updates.